How to pre-render ComposeView items in a RecyclerView to avoid delays in Jetpack Compose?
I'm using ComposeView inside a RecyclerView item view. My goal is to pre-render items (e.g., the next and previous items in the list) to make scrolling smoother and ensure that the content is ready before it appears on the screen.
In a standard RecyclerView setup with typical Android Views, RecyclerView’s prefetching and caching mechanisms attach items close to the viewport, so the next and previous items are ready when scrolled into view.
However, with ComposeView, I’m encountering a delay because the setContent method is only called when the item becomes visible on screen. This behavior causes a visible lag since the next item isn’t composed or rendered until it’s about to enter the viewport.
Replacing RecyclerView with LazyColumn isn’t an option right now due to the complexity of the layout and the need to handle multiple view types in the list.
Is there any way to force ComposeView to attach to the window earlier or trigger composition without waiting for visibility? Or is there a reliable pattern to pre-render ComposeView items in a RecyclerView setup to avoid delays?
Example Code:
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
holder.composeView.setContent {
    MyComposableContent()
}

}
What I’m looking for:

Techniques to improve the pre-rendering behavior for ComposeView in a RecyclerView.
Workarounds or best practices for using Compose within
RecyclerView items.
Recommendations on how to handle smooth scrolling
and pre-rendering with Compose content in RecyclerView.


Maybe you can get some reference from this library. It allows rendering composables within native RecyclerView

Thank you for the suggestion! I checked out the GitHub link, and it’s definitely a helpful resource. However, my use case is a bit different—I need to use ComposeView inside a traditional RecyclerView, rather than replacing the RecyclerView entirely with a Compose-based 'ComposeRecyclerView'.

So, are you experiencing lagging experienc in release build as well?

Yes, it doesn't appear to be related to the build type. After debugging, I found that the adjacent element is not being laid out until it actually becomes visible. This is because of ComposeView being used as an item view.

I'm not sure but this article might help you as it explains things about how composition of items works in recyclerview(with composables)
